# geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geb

I'm setting up some Geb tests and I'm getting "geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback " errors.  Geb will try to launch the testing browser window, but once it does,  none of my tests ever run and I get the above error.

I just did an automatic Firefox update to Firefox 32.0.2 so I suspect that the new version and the Selenium Web Driver aren't playing nice any more?    How do I fix that?

here is the Geb.config file I've been using?  I haven't changed it about 5 months and it's worked fine until now...

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import geb.waiting.WaitingSupport


reportsDir = "target/geb-reports"
driver = { 
    //path is specific to each machine. This is the path to firefox.exe
    def pathToBin = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin",pathToBin)
    def driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver();
    driverInstance.manage().window().maximize()
    driverInstance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed what I thought it was.   Upgraded the jar dependency to Selenium 2.43.1 and it works fine.  Was using 2.42.2 before